# Please help me delete a file?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a movie named Con Man. Apparently, in Windows, you cannot have a file name with the name CON in it. 
Can anyone please help me delete it?

It is stored in **F:\Movies\Con Man**
The name of the file that I want to delete is **Con.Man.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM]**

I know there are a lot of similar issues but I am not able to apply them that is why posting here. 
Thankyou

PS :: ***I am a noob!***

Edit: Found this on the internet but cant work it out
https://www.itechtics.com/how-to-createdelete-a-folder-named-con-in-windows/

Comment: I am not able to delete it. the error is "Invalid File Handle"

Comment: Did some tests, Con is a name of a device, and using con. will make both windows and command prompt fail given that it tries to access a device. Testing powershell now. I think Powershell is smart enough to do this.

Comment: What is the extension of the file?  del "F:\Movies\Con Man\Con.Man.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].<EXTENSION>"  <-  change <EXTENSION> to mkv or mp4 or whatever

Comment: Nope, Powershell can't do this either. That means you will need to use linux or another OS to actually get rid of this file. You can download a linux live cd and boot from that and rename or delete the file there. All it can't have is `con.` the rest is fine.

Comment: @mcalex just try to rename a textfile on your windows system to a file called `con.man.txt` and you'll find out it will fail.

Comment: @mcalex its mp4 and I cant do anything with it neither rename nor delete nor copy paste nothing!
Found this https://www.itechtics.com/how-to-createdelete-a-folder-named-con-in-windows/

Comment: @LPChip umm, yeah, but the file is already there?  In any event, my comment seems to be pretty much the answer so all good.

Comment: @mcalex not really, you need a special path in order to be able to delete it, although I don't seem to be able to use this trick ti create a file with this name to experiment on... aw...

Comment: Ah, got it to work. The first parameter must use \\... and if you do that, the 2nd file can then be ambiguous. So this will work: `ren "\\.\C:\temp\test.txt" "Con.Man.txt"` while this will not: `ren "C:\temp\test.txt" "\\.\C:\temp\Con.Man.txt"`

Comment: huh. I tried ren:  "A duplicate file name exists or the file cannot be found", but I created the "Con Man" directory first, cd'd into it and tried ren relatively, not absolutely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open **Command Prompt**
2. Type `del "\\.\F:\Movies\Con Man\Con.Man.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4"` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This works because the \.\ prefix will allow access to the drive directly without going through some drivers which prevents access to con files.

> The error message occurs appears when the file you are trying to
>   delete is given a reserved name. Using reserved names is prohibited by
>   Microsoft and should not be trifled with.
>
> The Microsoft Naming Conventions provide that files or folders on your
>   system should not be named CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4,
>   COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6,
>   LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. This is because these names are reserved names
>   in the Windows operating system, meaning they are used for a specific
>   purpose by the Windows operating system and should not be used
>   anywhere else. You should also avoid following the above names
>   immediately by an extension, for example, NUL.txt. In case you want
>   some more details, you can refer to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#namespaces) on Microsoft’s
>   website.

[Source](https://appuals.com/fix-invalid-file-handle-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Do you mind explaining *why* that works and the other way doesn't?

Comment: @mastov This works because the \\.\ prefix will allow access to the drive directly without going through some drivers which prevents access to *con* files.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the command line. Start it by typing `cmd` in the Start menu and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the command line window, type this command:

```
del "\\.\F:\Movies\Con Man\Con.Man.2018.720p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4"
```

It should get rid of the file. Similar commands can be used for other problematic files.

(By the way, the `.mp4` extension is my guess because you haven't provided it. It may actually be different, adjust it accordingly.)

If the folder also resists deletion, empty it and use this command:

```
rd "\\.\F:\Movies\Con Man"
```